# MicrosoftMvcAjax.js - Is there a CDN for the MVC 2 version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, cdn

I found this [link](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/mvc/1.0/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js) for the MicrosoftMVCAjax file for ASP.net MVC 1. Changing the url like [so](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/mvc/2.0/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js) for version 2 yields a 404.

Does anyone know what the correct URL is (if it exists)? If not - does someone know when we can expect this to be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC 2 is not on CDN yet (and sorry, but I don't know when it will be available :-( ):

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#ASPNET_MVC_Releases_on_the_CDN_5